New 90 TB/10 drive RAID 5 array state: clean, degraded, recovering. Why, and how long will it take to recover?
I've just created a new RAID 5 array in in Debian with mdadm:
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=10 /dev/sd[bcdefghijk]
&
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
and im confused as to why its in a degraded state and needs to resync the hot spare?
mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Nov 21 00:30:50 2024
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 87896742912 (81.86 TiB 90.01 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 9766304768 (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 10
     Total Devices : 10
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Nov 21 00:39:23 2024
             State : clean, degraded, recovering
    Active Devices : 9
   Working Devices : 10
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Rebuild Status : 0% complete

              Name : NAS-01:0  (local to host NAS-01)
              UUID : ce0174c2:d5ba7e08:2c765eaf:cf542fa5
            Events : 246

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       3       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
       4       8       80        4      active sync   /dev/sdf
       5       8       96        5      active sync   /dev/sdg
       6       8      112        6      active sync   /dev/sdh
       7       8      128        7      active sync   /dev/sdi
       8       8      144        8      active sync   /dev/sdj
      10       8      160        9      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdk

What am i doing wrong?

RAID5 with 10 10TB drives? You are guaranteed to lose the array at some point. Never use RAID5 with hard disks, especially modern high-capacity hard disks (so BER starts to matter, and rebuild times rise to space). Read this and this. Even tradiitonal RAID6 is dangerous for anything larger than ~4T; give ZFS or something like this a try, it is specially designed to counteract bit errors, which are the more probable the higher capacity there is.

This may be a record for worst RAID5 practice. What is the percent complete?

@GregAskew Nah.  I've encountered 20+ disk RAID5 arrays.  With individual disk block size set to 1 MB - so each RAID string was 20+ MB.  OK, they were only 1 TB drives, but that's only because larger drives weren't available at the time.  I'm sure the "admins" in charge would have done the same with 16 TB drives if they could have.

https://imgur.com/a/xr9w1Ae

"How long will it take" - you can work that out from when it was started, when it is now, and the reported percent completed. Don't be surprised if it's a few days. Then think about how long it will take to recover if a disk has to be replaced.

Strongly seconding the recommendation for RAID 6 - but whatever you do, make sure you set up regular media patrol / disk scrubbing. Verifying the media in a planned fashion is a very good method to avoid undetected bit rot that may pile up to a point where errors cannot be corrected any more. Undetected bit rot is especially problematic during rebuilding/recovering from disk failure and guaranteed to bring down a RAID 5 array. With RAID 6, your chances for successful rebuilding are way better. And for completeness: RAID is no alternative to backup.

You've done nothing wrong. The array is "resyncing" because you made it only nine minutes ago. Creating a RAID array is not instantaneous, you tell it what disks to use, but then it has to go through the entire array making sure that each set of blocks (8 data blocks and two parity blocks in this case) are coherent. It starts this process at the beginning of the array, and goes through to the end. And because it doesn't distinguish between this initial sync and a resync, it calls it a resync even though there wasn't one before.
Edit: To answer the second part, "how long will it take?" I can't answer that; your best bet is to look at the reported percent complete. It depends on your specific hardware - controllers, controller and disk geometry, OS, CPU, and phase of the moon. That said, you can go ahead and use the array now. If it needs to write something, it will write it correctly, even when that's out beyond the limit of what's been synced; when the sync process reaches that block, it will see it's correct and not change anything.


What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to use RAID5.
There is no point of addressing the precise question you're asking, because the way you're attempting to use your hard disks is simply a worst practice.  We're here for a reasonable practices. Also it's explained in the other answer.
This article has a nice concrete reference

A paper presented at FAST in 2007 by Google reveals that the probability of losing data during recovery from unrecoverable errors (UREs) alone on an array of 8 - 8TB SATA drives is over 98%.

Well, you have 10 drives of 10TB, so you'll have more than 98% probability of data loss. This is called guaranteed data loss, my dear.
Never use RAID5 with hard disks.
A separate issue is a bit errors. Even if all disks are "healthy" and no need to recover, there will eventually be undetected bad reads. Should that happen with data extent, there'll be bad picture or bad frame in a movie or a bad letter in a book, sad, but it's not a big deal. Should it be a filesystem structure... you'll potentially lose the whole filesystem, all 90 TB, how nice is that?
I don't know which are the specs of your disks, but typical bit error rate (BER) or uncorrected error rate (URE) is around 10^-14. But note this:

According to a study performed at CERN (because they were regularly losing data – reference below) the experienced bit failure rate was nine orders of magnitude higher than that reported by drive manufacturers (10^7 versus 10^16)!

CERN's source of failures was cosmic rays, and they're underground. Are you too? If not, you'll definitely have higher rates due to cosmic rays!
There are various other studies on the subject, including this one from Microsoft, which more or less confirm the severity of the problem. I encountered problems due to UREs myself.
A good introduction into this topic is this question.
I also leave it as a suggestion: with drives over 4TB always use the storage structures that incorporate checksums natively for integrity, of which most popular is ZFS, but also LVM RAID (which is mdadm on steroids, by the way), BTRFS and the upcoming bcachefs (which doesn't support erasure coding yet, it's work in progress, and I wouldn't yet use in production, but I have it in testing and it performs great).
Never use RAID5 with hard disks. Your best choice today would be ZFS RAIDZ2, and you'll be also able to enhance its write performance with a pair of SSDs for ZIL (or a battery-backed DRAM SSD, which is considered to "never fail", so it should be able to perform alone,  and it is much faster than "traditional" SSDs).

Never use RAID5 with hard disks.  IMO that's a bit strong.  A 5-disk RAID-5 array using 1 TB drives could provide acceptable performance and availability if you happen have those drives sitting around.  But yeah, I can't think of any reason today not to use something like a RAID1 of two 4 TB SSDs.  FWIW, I like to put a ZFS RAIDZ2 on top of hardware-mirrored RAID1 LUNs.  :-)

This entire answer is an opinion.  A correct opinion!  But, still, it doesn't actually answer the question.

There's a difference between uncorrected read errors and undetected read errors.  With the ECC used by current hard drives, it takes more bit-flips to produce an undetectable error than it takes to produce an uncorrectable one.

@MikeAndrews this answer is heavily backed up by countless statistics, some of papers I cited. That's facts. This answer is an inference from these facts, not just an opinion. Well, and technically it answers the question asked at the bottom: what's done wrong? — RAID5 used.

@Mark there is a difference, of course, but for this case it is not very important. Either one will cause the same damage. The URE will manifest itself harder so it'll likely be discovered earlier. Undetected errors, though much harder to encounter, are quite probable here, considering the capacity in question, and since it's a silent corruption, could manifest themselves much more damaging.


Why? To fix the parity.  Actually, if these are new disks, zero filled, the parity might be right, but it is going to do the work anyway.  Note that it is fully functional (though a bit slow) already.
How long?  Do cat /proc/mdstat and it will tell you.  Note that this will be wrong, as it assumes that the drive speed is constant.  In reality, it will slow down over time.  It will probably add 10% to 25% to the time.  I suspect this slowdown to be because it is farther out or in on the disk.

